# Why can't I log into the Discord.js client?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This code isn't working, it never logs `Ready!` to the console. It's also not logging out any errors, so I believe it may have logged in correctly but just isn't working. Does anyone have any pointers?

```
var Discord = require("discord.js");
var client = new Discord.Client();

client.login('myEmail', 'myPassword', output);

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("Ready!");
});

function output(error, token) {
        console.log("errorz!");
        if (error) {
            console.log("There was an error logging in: ${error}");
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("`Logged in. Token: ${token}`");
        }
}
```

Just to make sure I am doing this right, I have put this in a file called `discord-fisher.js` and I am running it using `node discord-fisher.js` from the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the documentation for Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=login) for `Client#login`:

> `.login( token )`
>
> Logs the client in, establishing a websocket connection to Discord.

So when you use `login`, you don't provide your email or password details, you provide your API token *associated with your account*.

Comment: Also as per documentation, logging in with email and password: http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_client.html#login-email-password-callback

Comment: @Amorris What version do you have installed? The documentation I linked was from the official website on the latest stable version, 11.1.0, and on all the examples it uses the token.

Comment: I have version 11.1.0 installed. I guess they removed support for email and password login. Where would I get my token?

Comment: @Amorris Maybe follow [this](https://github.com/Chikachi/DiscordIntegration/wiki/How-to-get-a-token-and-channel-ID-for-Discord) on registering an application and getting a token?

Comment: I have figured it out. [This](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/updating) page provides a method of accessing your token.